# How would I be able to Add, Multiply, and Subtract using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

When I click buttons in my program, they are logged in the console, but If I want to add thew the numbers how Would I get them to be put together? So if I press 1+5, then I press the equal button it will just pop up as:
1
+
5 =

So how would I be able to get 6, or any other calculations.

I also want to know How I'm able to put display the numbers in the black box (input/screen) when numbers are pressed.

```js
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green"

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What numbers are pressed
document.querySelector(".buttons8").onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    console.log(`${e.target.dataset.num}`);
    //do something
  }
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-grey{
 background: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="calculator8">
 <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>
</div>



 </section>
```

Comment: I had made you a good start in your previous post, I see you haven't change your code yet!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193406/how-to-make-a-calculator-using-javascript-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval()` method to evaluate an expression, but keep in mind that using `eval()` is a security risk - never try to evaluate code or values that might be coming from outside your application.

In the code below I used an array to keep track of all the clicked parameters. When the user clicks on `=` then the array is joined into a string and evaluated. You might also want to add some checks to make sure the expression is valid, like maybe use a for loop to verify before evaluating.

**Test and run below:**

```js
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green"

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What numbers are pressed
var expression = [];

document.querySelector(".buttons8").onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    if(e.target.innerHTML !== "=") {
      expression.push(e.target.innerHTML);
    } else {
      console.log( eval(expression.join("")) );
      expression = [];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-grey{
 background: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="calculator8">
 <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>
</div>



 </section>
```